# How to give data without label for prediction using NaiveBayes algorithm in Apache Spark:Mllib in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I am working on diabetes prediction in Scala language using Apache Spark. I trained the data that was stored in a csv file. Now using this trained data I want to predict the result of data that does not have any labels, it has only the features.The data to be predicted is stored in another csv file. I am using Naive Bayes algorithm for it. The code is:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("NaiveBayesExample").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.bindAddress","127.0.0.1")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val data= sc.textFile("/path/to/file/diabetes.data")
val data1=sc.textFile("/path/to/file/predict.data")

val parsedData = data.map { line =>
val parts = line.split(',')
LabeledPoint(parts(8).toDouble,Vectors.dense(parts(0).toDouble, parts(1).toDouble, parts(2).toDouble,parts(3).toDouble,
parts(4).toDouble,parts(5).toDouble,parts(6).toDouble,parts(7).toDouble))
}

val model = NaiveBayes.train(parsedData, lambda = 1.0, modelType = "multinomial")
```

The file diabetes.data contains the training data and predict.data contains the samples that are to be predicted. I cannot apply the **LabeledPoint** to the data to be predicted as it does not contain any labels. I tried using it as:

```
val parsedData1 = data1.map { line =>
  val parts = line.split(',')
  LabeledPoint(parts(),Vectors.dense(parts(0).toDouble, parts(1).toDouble, parts(2).toDouble,parts(3).toDouble,
    parts(4).toDouble,parts(5).toDouble,parts(6).toDouble,parts(7).toDouble))
}
val predictionAndLabels = parsedData1.map { case LabeledPoint(label,features) =>
val prediction = model.predict(features)
(prediction,label)
}
```

But this gave me these errors:

```
Error:(47, 25) not enough arguments for method apply: (i: Int)String in class Array.
Unspecified value parameter i.
LabeledPoint(parts(),Vectors.dense(parts(0).toDouble, parts(1).toDouble, parts(2).toDouble,parts(3).toDouble,

Error:(69, 54) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint 
required: Nothing 
val predictionAndLabels = parsedData1.map { case LabeledPoint(label,features) =>
```

I want to predict the result of the samples that do not have labels? How can I do it?

Comment: *What* error? Could you please add the concrete error message to your question? (Use the little gray `edit` button to update your question).

Comment: Please use the DataFrame API that is the primary one starting from version 2.0.0